Getting errors while using slot property for MUI DatePicker component
I would like to override some components from the DatePicker component from the MUI library but I am getting errors in the console when I do so.
Code
   <DatePicker
              slots={{
                textField: 'div',
              }}
              slotProps={{
                textField: {
                  className: 'test'
                },
              }}
              onAccept={(val) => {
                setDate(val);
                setOpen(false);
              }}
              onClose={(e) => {
                setOpen(false);
              }}
              value={tempDate}
              onChange={(newDate) => {
                setTempDate(newDate);
              }}
              open={open}
            />

However, I'm getting these errors when I run this
Warning: React does not recognize the `ownerState` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `ownerstate` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `error`.
If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: error="false" or error={value.toString()}.

I presume these errors are occurring because I have overided the DatePicker TextField that was taking in some props data. When I remove the slots prop the errors go away. While taking a look at the docs, I haven't seen any information on how to handle this issue. Can anyone help me debug this?

Before that you should read the documentation carefully. Usually a MUI slot should be a MUI component, not a string. textField: TextField from '@mui/material' or PickersTextField if enableAccessibleFieldDOMStructure is true. document

Ah yeah, seems like that was my issue. I went ahead and removed the slots altogether and used the slotProps to get the result I needed. Thank you!
